# Propel : How to use conditional clauses or results

Tags: propel

I would like Propel to create a query with conditional clauses and get conditional results.

For a MySQL example I would like something like :

```
SELECT product.id FROM product WHERE IF(product.promo=0, product.price, product.promo_price) > 100
```

And something like :

```
SELECT IF(product.promo=0, product.price, product.promo_price) AS price FROM product WHERE id=123
```

I dug the Propel documentation but keyword IF is just ubiquitous when I use search tool. Therefore here I am :

Which Method can I use to create such a query ?

I made it happen using `where` method :

```
ProductQuery::create()->where('IF(product.promo=0, product.price, product.promo_price) > ?', $myprice);
```

But I suppose it's only gonna work with MySQL.

What is the proper way to make it ?

Regards,

Etienne

Comment: Yep, that'll only work in MySQL, but I think that's you're only option.

Comment: Can't you just use CASE switch instead of IF()? Shouldn't that work in other dbs too? Like: 
ProductQuery::create()->where('CASE WHEN product.promo=0 THEN product.price ELSE product.promo_price END > ?', $myprice)